# Image not completely showing in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I'm using HorizontalScrollView to create a horizontal image gallery but for some reason the first image is not completely being shown and I cannot scroll left anymore and is cropped however when I rotate the device it shows it fine. I tried playing with fill_parent and wrap_content both in my linearlayout and horizontalscroll view but non worked.
 [image]
Here is my xml:

> ```
> <HorizontalScrollView
>     android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:fillViewport="true"
>     android:measureAllChildren="false"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:scrollbars="none"
>    android:layout_below="@id/image" >
>     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/gallery"
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
>     </LinearLayout>
> </HorizontalScrollView>
> ```

and here is my code:

```
 myGallery = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(images.get(i)).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_photos).resize(150,  150).into(imageView);
        myGallery.addView(imageView);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added margin_left to my LinearLayout and it shows it now. I don't know if this is hacky or not but it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is actually related to the `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` attribute. In my case, if I deleted this attribute it worked just fine. Can't explain why, but maybe you can try this.